# Why are parentheses mandatory when using route helper methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Knowing that this is possible in Ruby:

```
method_name param, other_method other_param
```

Which would be the equivalent in another programming language to:

```
method_name(param, other_method(other_param))
```

Why is it that it is **not** possible to do that with the auto-generated route helpers, which are methods just like the others?

For example:

```
<%= link_to ticket.subject, ticket_path(ticket.id) %>
```

Is valid — it returns, for example, `<a href="/tickets/1">Lorem ipsum.</a>`, but:

```
<%= link_to ticket.subject, ticket_path ticket.id %>
```

Is not — it returns a `unexpected tIDENTIFIER` error.

Comment: Are you sure that `method_name param, other_method other_param` works as expected? `f g x` is `f(g(x))` but `f 6, g x` is a SyntaxError.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`method_name param, other_method other_param` is not possible in Ruby, so it's not possible with route helpers either because it is ambiguous.

There's even a [section](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=jcUbTcr5XWwC&lpg=PA183&ots=fJDkAd3xiE&dq=ruby%20optional%20parentheses&pg=PA184#v=onepage&q&f=false) about this in The Ruby Programming Language by Matz.

Example:

```
irb(main):001:0> def link_to(a, b)
irb(main):002:1> puts a, b
irb(main):003:1> end
:link_to
irb(main):004:0> def foo(a)
irb(main):005:1> puts 'foo'
irb(main):006:1> end
:foo
irb(main):007:0> link_to 'hello', foo 'abc'
SyntaxError: (irb):7: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
link_to 'hello', foo 'abc'
                      ^
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):008:0> link_to 'hello', foo('abc')
foo
hello

nil
```

Comment: Not only your answer explained succinctly, but the section in Matz book is crystal clear. Thanks heaps!